# WordPress in Laravel public folder returns 404 not found

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've a laravel installed in /dev.domain.com/ and RootDocument is set to /dev.domain.com/public

The laravel works without any problem and then I install WordPress in newly created directory named "blog" under the laravel's public folder

Wordpress path : /dev.domain.com/public/blog

On localhost I'm can access /blog and setup wordpress as usual, however the problem come with I deploy to live server by cloning with git. The laravel path works fine but when I try to access /blog directory in public folder it returns **404 Not found**

Below is the Laravel

/dev.domain.com/public/.htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect non ssl to ssl
    # and don't redirect subdomain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and Wordpress

/dev.domain.com/public/blog/.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

# Disable WordPress front-end
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-includes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-login\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-content
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried to add this one but no chance to make it works

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
```

Above

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this recipe](http://www.cesarserna.com/htaccess-rewrite-rules-laravel-lumen-wordpress/), it works for me.

Add to Laravel `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ #
```

And change these lines in Wordpress `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```